# how to disable the checkbox value for others after it stored to firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, loops, android-layout, firebase-realtime-database

Here I am working on a project based on carparking in android. In this the user first selects the complex and then selects the parking slot then books the place this is my scenario. Here's my question is if a user book a place in the particular complex then how to disable that particular place for the other users.

I give the places in checkbox and I don't want to use radio button because one user can book a place for his friends so a user can book two places.

I just added the values and other details on the firebase database and my code for adding the values in the database is.

This my code for uploading values in the database:

```
           checkupdate = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(coID).child(slotID).child(place).child(phone).child("place");
                        Avilsize = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(coID).child(slotID).child(place).child(phone);

                        HashMap<String, Object> avilsizetMap = new HashMap<>();

                        if (place.equals("place1"))
                        {
                            int a = check + 1;
                            bookplace = (String) "place1";

                            check = a;
                            String b = "value" + a;
                            HashMap<String, Object> checkmap = new HashMap<>();
                            checkmap.put("Value", "place1");
                            checkupdate.child(b).updateChildren(checkmap);

                        }
                        if (place.equals("place2")) {
                            int a = check + 1;

                            bookplace = bookplace + "/" + (String) "place2";

                            check = a;
                            String b = "value" + a;
                            HashMap<String, Object> checkmap = new HashMap<>();
                            checkmap.put("Value", "place2");
                            checkupdate.child(b).updateChildren(checkmap);

                        }
                        if (place.equals("place3")) {
                            int a = check + 1;
                            bookplace = bookplace + "/" + (String) "place3";

                            check = a;
                            String b = "value" + a;
                            HashMap<String, Object> checkmap = new HashMap<>();
                            checkmap.put("Value", "place3");
                            checkupdate.child(b).updateChildren(checkmap);

                        }
                        if (place.equals("place4")) {
                            int a = check + 1;
                            bookplace = bookplace + "/" + (String) "place4";

                            check = a;
                            String b = "value" + a;
                            HashMap<String, Object> checkmap = new HashMap<>();
                            checkmap.put("Value", "place4");
                            checkupdate.child(b).updateChildren(checkmap);

                        }
                        if (place.equals("place5")) {
                            int a = check + 1;
                            bookplace = bookplace + "/" + (String) "place5";

                            check = a;
                            String b = "value" + a;
                            HashMap<String, Object> checkmap = new HashMap<>();
                            checkmap.put("Value", "place5");
                            checkupdate.child(b).updateChildren(checkmap);

                        }
                        if (place.equals("place6")) {
                            int a = check + 1;
                            bookplace = bookplace + "/" + (String) "place6";

                            check = a;
                            String b = "value" + a;
                            HashMap<String, Object> checkmap = new HashMap<>();
                            checkmap.put("Value", "place6");
                            checkupdate.child(b).updateChildren(checkmap);
                        }
                        avilsizetMap.put("book_place", bookplace);
                        Avilsize.updateChildren(avilsizetMap);
```

my database structure
[image: this my structure of database]

i tried one set of code to retrieve the values but its not working and the code is here

```
                       final List<String >  areas = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                            String areaName = areaSnapshot.child("Value").getValue(String.class);
                            areas.add(areaName);
                        }
                        for (String area : areas)
                        {
                            if(area.equals("place1"))
                            {
                                Place1.setChecked(true);
                            }
                            if(area.equals("place2")){
                                Place2.setChecked(true);
                            }
                            if(area.equals("Place3")){
                                Place3.setChecked(true);
                            }
                            if(area.equals("Place4")){
                                Place4.setChecked(true);
                            }
                            if(area.equals("Place5")){
                                Place5.setChecked(true);
                            }
                            if(area.equals("Place6")){
                                Place6.setChecked(true);
                            }
                        }
```

this is my layout in xml

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="20dp">

              <TableLayout
                 android:padding="3dp"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:stretchColumns="3">
                    <TableRow>
                       <CheckBox
                           android:id="@+id/pl1"
                           android:layout_width="40dp"
                           android:layout_height="40dp"
                           android:tag="place1"
                           android:button="@drawable/checkbox_bg"
                           />
                       <CheckBox
                           android:id="@+id/pl2"
                           android:layout_width="40dp"
                           android:tag="place2"
                           android:layout_height="40dp"
                           android:button="@drawable/checkbox_bg"
                           />
                       <CheckBox
                           android:id="@+id/pl3"
                           android:layout_width="40dp"
                           android:tag="place3"
                           android:layout_height="40dp"
                           android:button="@drawable/checkbox_bg"
                           />
                    </TableRow>
              </TableLayout>

              <TableLayout
                 android:id="@+id/table2"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:padding="3dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:stretchColumns="3">
                    <TableRow>
                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/pl4"
                            android:layout_width="40dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:tag="place4"
                            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_bg"
                            />
                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/pl5"
                            android:layout_width="40dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:tag="place5"
                            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_bg"
                            />
                       <CheckBox
                           android:id="@+id/pl6"
                           android:layout_width="40dp"
                           android:layout_height="40dp"
                           android:tag="place6"
                           android:button="@drawable/checkbox_bg"
                           />
                     </TableRow>
               </TableLayout>

          </LinearLayout>

         <Button
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:fontFamily="cursive"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_bg"
                android:text="Book" />
```

i hope that someone give me a solution thankyou...

Comment: Try to change the value of the "Value" child in the firebase database. I don't know if you already tried this, but the value of the child in database is "Place4", with capital P, while in your code is "place4"... :)

Comment: @GusCorreia thanks for the help but i already tried it.